# Correcting for ARCH effect in VAR and impulse response results

Tags: time-series, garch, vector-autoregression, impulse-response, variance-decomposition

I find significant ARCH effect in my series when running a VAR analysis

$Y_t=(y_{1,t};y_{2,t};y_{3,t};y_{4,t};y_{5,t})^\top$

I have two questions:

1. Does the ARCH effect impact the impulse response and variance decomposition results?
2. Is there a specific way for correcting the data for ARCH effect in terms of VAR?

I know how to do it for OLS where I have 1 dependent variable but I wonder if there is some special way for doing it when performing VAR analysis.

Comment: Estimate a VAR-MGARCH model where MGARCH stands for your favourite version of multivariate GARCH. You can do this with e.g. `rmgarch` package in R.

Comment: Hi Richard, super useful answer, thank you! I can see that in the package there is varxfit and I will check it out. However, do you think I need to have the ARCH effect taken care to use the impulse response and variance decomposition features from the vars package in R?

Comment: Better to take care of than to ignore. Also, I suspect you cannot do IRF and FEVD properly with `vars` since it does not have the functionality to incorporate ARCH effects.